# ASRA while reading a TSQ

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe, cics

I am getting ASRA abend while trying to read from a TSQ. Will ASRA occur if we try to read from a TSQ that is already deleted? what all could be the possible reasons?

Comment: You need to find out what caused the ASRA. If you have numeric (non-binary) data which you are doing arithmetic with, then not having the data there would lead to an ASRA. So would a vast amount of things. You need to track down what caused the abend (one of your other questions) and that will give you a good starting-point.

Answer (score 2):

ASRA is sort of a catch-all error that says CICS identified a program check state and ended your transaction for you.  It could be anything.  You can get more detail from the CICS started task and it's logs, or from your whatever ABEND reporting product your installation has installed.

However, if you are getting the ASRA while you are doing a READQ TS with the INTO(*varname*) option, make sure you own the storage of *varname* and that the length is enough to fit the largest possible record on the queue.

Also, if you use the length option, make sure that you have it set correctly.  If you ask for 32k bytes from the TS queue into a 100 byte area, you will get an ASRA.

But all of the above is only one possible reason for it, you really need to determine what sort of ASRA you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

If the Temporary Storage Queue is already deleted, you shouldn't get an ASRA but a QIDERR condition, which if not handled will give you a different abend, an AEYH abend.

ASRA's are just CICS codes for an S0C* abend, which I am going to presume in this case would be an S0C4 or protection exception. A protection exception happens when you try to write to (or sometimes read from) storage that you don't have permission to.